# Cannot assign to overloaded dereference (*) operator

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, overloading, operator-keyword

I have overloaded dereference operator for my template class:

```
 template <class T> class Node {

 public:
     T *pointer;
     T operator*() { return *pointer; }
 };
```

I want to be able to write to the pointer in main:

```
Node<int> n;
*n = 33;
```

But I get this error:

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

How should I overload this operator to be able to write to the pointer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just give it `T&` as the return type. Then you have an lvalue. The problem right now is that you're returning a copy of the object pointed to.

Comment: Ok, this works, I just didn't allocated memory for pointer, now it works with T&